# CSS hide data-toggle

Tags: css

It is possible with css hide this: `<a data-toggle="collapse"></a>` without hide the first `<a>`? with just css?

```
<a href="edit.html">
   <i class="pull-left fa fa-lg fa-calendar-plus-o" aria-hidden="true"></i>
</a>
```

```html
  <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.6.3/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-T8Gy5hrqNKT+hzMclPo118YTQO6cYprQmhrYwIiQ/3axmI1hQomh7Ud2hPOy8SP1" crossorigin="anonymous">
   <li>
      <a href="edit.html">
       <i class="pull-left fa fa-lg fa-calendar-plus-o" aria-hidden="true"></i>
      </a>
       <a data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapse" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapse" class="">Collapse</a>
    </li>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `data-toggle` attribute as a selector like so ...

```
[data-toggle="collapse"] {
    display: none;
}
```

I have to point out that this is not a good seperation of concerns and/or best practice.

Answer (score 1):

You can use css selectors:

```css
a:nth-of-type(2){
display:none;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.6.3/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-T8Gy5hrqNKT+hzMclPo118YTQO6cYprQmhrYwIiQ/3axmI1hQomh7Ud2hPOy8SP1" crossorigin="anonymous">
   <li>
      <a href="edit.html">
       <i class="pull-left fa fa-lg fa-calendar-plus-o" aria-hidden="true"></i>
      </a>
       <a data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapse" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapse" class="">Collapse</a>
    </li>
```

Answer (score 1):

```css
a:last-child{
display:none;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.6.3/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-T8Gy5hrqNKT+hzMclPo118YTQO6cYprQmhrYwIiQ/3axmI1hQomh7Ud2hPOy8SP1" crossorigin="anonymous">
   <li>
      <a href="edit.html">
       <i class="pull-left fa fa-lg fa-calendar-plus-o" aria-hidden="true"></i>
      </a>
       <a data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapse" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapse" class="">Collapse</a>
    </li>
```

You can use :last-child to reference to the last  tag

Answer (score 0):

```
[data-toggle="collapse"] {
    display: none;
}
```